# httpfs for hadoop apache Download

Tags: hadoop, httpfs

Iam using Apache Hadoop-2.7.1 on Centos 7 Operating System.

To setup HttpFs, this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/ServerSetup.html) suggests to install HttpFs. I do not find any binary available for it.

Is there an alternative method to configure HttpFs for Hadoop?

Comment: iam new to linux so apologize me if i didn't express well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`HttpFs`** is included in the binary tarball of Apache Hadoop itself. You need not download it separately.

The configuration files `httpfs-env.sh` and `httpfs-site.xml` are available under `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/` directory.

The startup script `httpfs.sh` is under `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/`.

To configure the embedded Tomcat of HttpFs, look for the configuration files under `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/httpfs/tomcat/conf/`.